# Do elementary transformations affect the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a general doubt regarding the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix. I know that the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are the diagonal entries themselves, but do elementary transformations affect the eigenvalues?

We know that every matrix can be reduced to a diagonal matrix via elementary transformations. The matrix we obtain after applying the elementary Transformations will have the same eigenvalues as the original matrix that we started with.

Comment: How do you reduce $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ to a diagonal matrix using elementary transformations?

Comment: What is the need to reduce this matrix into diagonal matrix?

Comment: It's already a diagonal matrix and so Eigen Values of such matrix will be $0,0$.

Comment: No it is not. A diagonal matrix is a square matrix such that all entries outside the main diagonal are equal to $0$. That's not the case in my example.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ohh sorry. I got what you are trying to convey. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Elementary transformation changes the eigen values. Am I right?

Comment: How do you define elementary transformation? Are you talking about [this](http://www.simumath.com/library/book.html?code=Matr_Alg_element_transforms_of_matrices)?

Comment: Yes, sir I was talking about this.

Comment: Then, yes, they affect the eigenvalues, but I see that you alredy have an answer.

Comment: What about a triangular matrix. If I have a matrix which looks like triangular matrix and I make a single elementary Transformation to make this matrix into triangular matrix, then the Eigen Values will be equal.

Comment: I did not claim that *all* elementary transformations affect the eigenvalues, only that some do.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit? Because I am really confused regarding this?

Comment: I really don't see how can I put it in a simpler way.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen values change when you apply elementary transformation.

**Example**
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
This has eigen values 2 and 1 now do elementary tranformation $R_1\rightarrow0.5R_1-0.5R_2$, The matrix becomes $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ with eigenvalues 1, 1